# ArcGIS Pro or ArcGIS Online: How to show one feature when another is selected?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

I'm plotting a map of origins and destinations, and I connected these points using the XY to Line tool. Unfortunately, there are too many features for the map to be legible, and there's no easy way to narrow down the data. I'd like to make an interactive map where when the viewer clicks an origin point, the corresponding destination point will appear and so will the line connecting them. Can this be done?

Or, can this be achieved by a method aside from my rough idea? I'm working in ArcGIS Pro and will export this to ArcGIS Online.

Comment: So if you have a million lines currently displaying, you are happy to have just a million origin points displaying?

Comment: I would have all the origin points display at once, and then clicking them would make the corresponding destination point and the line between them appear. It's still a lot of points, but it's more legible than all the lines.

Comment: I don't know enough about ArcGIS Online maps, not sure you can capture that on click event and use that to drive the display of features in other layers. The interactive you seek might exist in experience builder?

Comment: Sounds like a flow map: https://storymaps.arcgis.com/stories/a99b52c4de174b47bdf3e42232c9bc63

Comment: Hack would be to use symbology to make lines near-invisible (transparent, colored to match background), and when someone clicks on a point, it should also intersect the line, and the line will pop up visibly.